# Model Selection for Dynamic Environments with one label data (big data)

Tags: machine-learning, outliers, supervised-learning, unsupervised-learning, bigdata

I'm wondering that how can I handle this situation with unsupervised/semi-supervised/supervised approach in real time (for each record online):

I have normal data of a company for a year. It is Big Data (I mention this because it may help in proposing solution - I'm going to work on Spark). Data is only labeled with normal. But there are some problems:

1) Distribution of data with normal class, can vary. This means its features values can vary after building a model because of dynamic environment and adding/removing some sensors (data is received from sensors and adding a sensor affects other sensor values).

2) I want to find a solution (build a model) for separating normal data from probable abnormal data which will have in future. The abnormal data types(classes) can be different considering its effect on system.

Now, how can I build a model (find a solution) to handle this situation? I think because of huge amount of data that I have there is a way to distinguish normal one from the abnormal one. I hope it be true!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you know which features may change in future or at least will you get to know that this particular feature future value ranges will be entirely different than the past one, when change will happen?

Comment: approximately all features are changed but it certainly will not be completely different. It is somehow in range overall. The point is that, if a change occurs, it somehow change the all feature in a fixed ratio with a formula but abnormal data is result of changing some features in a specific way and distribution of that record is  a bit different with normal one.

Comment: Abnormal records are outlier (but their types are different - suppose we have 4 classes of outlier but overall are outlier). Now, I'm thinking about detecting such outliers from normal data while I have the mentioned limitations in big data manner (Spark)